# Gitlab CI choose between 2 manual jobs

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to know if there is any way to have 2 "manual jobs", in the same stage, and if one is triggered, the second is canceled.

Basically, what I want to do is to have 2 "manual jobs", one for continue my pipeline, and if it is triggered, the pipeline continue and the second "manual job" is canceled.

Or if the second manual job is the triggered, the first manual job is canceled and the pipeline stop.

I tried many thing but it doesn't seem to work and I didn't find topic about this kind of problematic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/directed_acyclic_graph/) to make sure `job 2` and `job 3` do not start until `manual job 1` finishes successfully, but as far as I know there is no way to easily cancel one job from another.

You could try using [Jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#cancel-a-job), but I'm not sure how to get ID of `manual job 1` from `manual job 2` and vice versa.

Cancelling the entire pipeline would be easy. All you need for that is to use [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `CI_PIPELINE_ID` (or `CI_PIPELINE_IID` - I'm not sure which would be the right one) and [Pipeline API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#cancel-a-pipelines-jobs).

Edit: I suppose, knowing the Pipeline ID, you could get all the jobs for the pipeline with [Jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#list-pipeline-jobs) and then parse the JSON into a map of Job names to IDs and finally use this map to cancel all jobs you want canceled.