# Is it possible in gitlab to do 2 manual jobs of which only one can be run?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Is it possible to add 2 manual jobs and only allow the execution of one of them? F.e. in the image below the promote job was started already, so the publish job should no longer be available or should be locked.

[Two manual jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVIFn.png)

I found this Question: [Gitlab CI choose between 2 manual jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63157641/gitlab-ci-choose-between-2-manual-jobs)

and it has similarities but I do not want to cancel the entire pipeline. I simply want to force to pick one out of the two manual jobs at this stage and deny the user to start both of them. So as soon as one of the two is running the other one should be locked.

I could not find anything in rules, etc. that would work for this.